# Как разделать почтовый сервер на два отдельных (антиспам и почта)?

Tags: linux, сервер, email, postfix, dovecot

коллеги.

На данный момент мой почтовый сервер не справляется с нагрузкой. Поэтому хочу антиспам защиту вынести на отдельный сервер.

Что я хочу сделать / Как я вижу данную реализацию.
fw - файрвол, ему назначен внешний адрес (5.5.5.5, он же mx для внешних отправителей).
srv1 - антиспам - postfix, rspamd (адрес 10.1.1.1).
srv2 - почтовик - postfix, dovecot, web-морда, БД (адрес 10.1.1.2, он же mx для локальных пользователей).
IMAP, POP3, HTTP трафик идет напрямую на srv2.

Входящая из-вне почта попадает на srv1, проверяется на спам и передается на srv2 (10.1.1.1 -> 10.1.1.2), где раскладывается в ящики пользователей.
Внутренние пользователи подключаются только к srv2 (10.1.1.2). Он отправляет почту во-вне, минуя srv1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На srv2, как я понимаю, нужно mysql открыть на интерфейсе 10.1.1.2, чтобы srv1 мог проверять есть ли адрес-получателя и в virtual_mailbox_maps на srv1 указать хост БД как 10.1.1.1. Или есть другой способ?

А вот дальше запутался... Не совсем понимаю, как это настроить в postfix. Вроде нужно правильно настроить master.cf, но что именно? Как postfix'у сказать, что на srv1 почту, после проверки rspamd, нужно передать на srv2 ? Подскажите пожалуйста.

*Может я и вовсе не правильный подход выбрал? Поясните, как правильнее сделать. Настроить все на одном сервере не проблема, но вот как правильно разделить, не знаю.*

Comment: А кроме антиспама что еще систему нагружает ? Т.е. есть ли смысл разделять нагрузку, если 90% уйдет на srv1 ... Почта без антиспама обычно вообще ничего не потребляет. Или скажем если mysql при работе антиспама и остальной системы то же ест довольно много, может его одного вынести на отдельный хост

Comment: кратко: 1. неясно, что у вас есть сейчас. 2. какой из компонентов «не справляется».

Comment: Основную нагрузку (основной тормоз) создает courier-imap. Да, сейчас он стоит. И передо мной стоит задача оптимизировать сервер, чтобы он работал быстрее. Сервер очень старый, раньше его ни кто толком не обслуживал. Решил сделать новый сервер и перенести туда всю почту.
Ящиков под 2000. Входящих в сутки (включая спам) порядка 60К, из которых спам от 60 до 85 %% (в зависимости от "сезонности"). Большая часть реальной почты бегает внутри домена. Так вот основную нагрузку создают курьер и антиспам. Я сразу хочу их разделить. В будущем кол-во ящиков будет только расти.